# AngularJS - unselect radio button

Tags: angularjs, radio-button

I have three of this radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="project" data-ng-model="vm.defaultProject" data-ng-value="projectUserConnection.project" />
```

An if I select one, I can not deselect it that all of the three are deselected.
Is there a possibility to do this, so that if I select the selected radio button that it became unselected?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have set up radio buttons correctly.See [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/25/radio-buttons-with-angularjs.aspx).

```
<label>
        <input type="radio" name="project"
               value="Some Value" ng-model="vm.defaultProject" />
        Radio 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="project"
               value="Some other value" ng-model="vm.defaultProject" />
        Radio 2
    ............
</label>
```